# Capture the progress percentage of 'bmaptool'

Tags: shell

I am trying to extract "percentage" status from "bmaptool" command.

For example:

```
sudo bmaptool copy image.wic.bz2 /dev/sdd
bmaptool: info: discovered bmap file 'image.wic.bmap'
bmaptool: info: block map format version 2.0
bmaptool: info: 1109994 blocks of size 4096 (4.2 GiB), mapped 664030 blocks (2.5 GiB or 59.8%)
bmaptool: info: copying image 'image.wic.bz2' to block device '/dev/sdd' using bmap file 'image.wic.bmap'
bmaptool: info: 20% copied
```

But the percentage string " % copied" is not shown after the pipeline.

```
sudo bmaptool copy image.wic.bz2 /dev/sdd | grep 'copied'
```

I take a look on the source of 'bmaptool'. The percentage is written to stderr.
I also try to use "stdbuf -e 0", but still can't fix it.

Is there any way to extract "percentage" information from "bmaptool"?

Comment: Try `sudo bmapthing ... 2>&1 | grep ...`

Comment: I try it. it looks all the messages are directed to pipeline, except the line with "percentage" status. Suspect it's caused by line buffer or the output message is from the child process of bmaptool...

Answer (score 1):

**`bmaptool v3.6** added the option **--psplash-pipe`** for publishing the percentage value to a named pipe (although not strictly for psplash) you can read from.

Comment: Thanks~ It did work. :)

`mkfifo /tmp/progress`
`bmaptool copy IMAGE /dev/sdX --psplash-pipe /tmp/progress`